# What is the XeTeX equivalent of \pdfcreationdate?

Tags: xetex, datetime

I need the time to 1-second resolution.

`datetime` uses `\pdfcreationdate` for this, but only under pdf(La)TeX.

As a result under XeLaTeX, this:

```
\usepackage{datetime}
...
\newtimeformat{hhmmss}{\twodigit{\THEHOUR}\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}\twodigit{\THESECOND}}
\settimeformat{hhmmss}
\currenttime
```

always produces `00` as the last two digits, eg:

```
113600
```

Comment: `\pdfcreationdate` is specific to pdfTeX (and LuaTeX); XeTeX has nothing of this kind, so it can use only the data provided by `\time` that contains only the minutes since midnight.

Comment: @egreg Perhaps make your comment an answer. The only way I can think of doing this is using shell escape to get a timestamp from a file, but that is then system and shell escape status dependent.

Comment: @egreg et al: Maybe I just move from XeTeX to LuaTeX?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no `\pdfcreationdate` command in XeTeX as in pdfTeX and LuaTeX. There is a technical reason, for this: the PDF file is produced by XeTeX in an asynchronous way, delivering the pages produced in `xdv` format to `xdvipdfmx`. In general, these files are kept in a temporary directory and the PDF is finally moved to the current directory at the end.

One could use the shell escape, checking the date of creation of the `.log` file, which is opened at the start of the job, but this would be system dependent.

### Emulate `\pdfcreationdate` in XeTeX

We can use LuaTeX also from XeTeX (or XeLaTeX)! Create the following file `creationdate.lua`:

```
os.remove("creationdate.timestamp")
io.output("creationdate.timestamp"):write(os.date("\\edef\\tempa{\\string D:%Y%m%d%H%M%S}\n\\def\\tempb{%z}"))\end{filecontents*}
```

Then put the following code before loading `datetime`:

```
\ifdefined\pdfcreationdate\else
\begingroup
  \ifnum\shellescape=1
    \immediate\write18{texlua creationdate.lua}
    \input{creationdate.timestamp}
    \def\tempc#1#2#3#4#5{#1#2#3'#4#5'}
    \edef\tempb{\expandafter\tempc\tempb}
    \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\pdfcreationdate{\tempa\tempb}}\x
  \fi
\fi
```

The file `creationdate.timestamp` will be removed, if existent, and a new one created with the current time in it, in a format similar to that produced by `\pdfcreationdate` in pdfTeX. Then it will be read in; the time shown will be that of the execution of the script. However, any recent TeX distribution should have `texlua` (because it has `luatex`), so this should be as system independent as possible.

Actually, what's written in `creationdate.timestamp` is something like

```
\edef\tempa{\string D:20120122195802}
\def\tempb{+0100}
```

and then its contents is massaged a bit to get it into, essentially,

```
\def\pdfcreationdate{D:20120122195802+01'00'}
```

that's the format requested by `datetime` (the `D` must have category code 12, because such is the one produced by `\pdfcreationdate` in (pdf|Lua)TeX).

A complete example, to be run with `--shell-escape`, as always (otherwise `\pdfcreationdate` will not be defined and `datetime` will show seconds as "00"); the macros do nothing if `\pdfcreationdate` is already present (so using `pdftex` or `luatex` as engines).

---

```
\begin{filecontents*}{creationdate.lua}
os.remove("creationdate.timestamp")
io.output("creationdate.timestamp"):write(os.date("\\edef\\tempa\{\\string D:%Y%m%d%H%M%S\}\n\\def\\tempb\{%z\}"))
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{standalone}
\ifdefined\pdfcreationdate\else
\begingroup
  \ifnum\shellescape=1
    \immediate\write18{texlua creationdate.lua}
    \input{creationdate.timestamp}
    \def\tempc#1#2#3#4#5{#1#2#3'#4#5'}
    \edef\tempb{\expandafter\tempc\tempb}
    \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\pdfcreationdate{\tempa\tempb}}\x
  \fi
\fi

\usepackage{datetime}
\newtimeformat{hhmmss}{\twodigit{\THEHOUR}\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}\twodigit{\THESECOND}}
\settimeformat{hhmmss}
\begin{document}
\currenttime
\end{document}
```

---

### An alternative way on Unix systems

Unfortunately, XeTeX doesn't sport the pdfTeX feature of `\input|<command>`, so an indirect way has to be taken, creating an auxiliary file to be read in.

- Create a shell script `creationdate.sh`

```
    #! /bin/sh
    rm -f $1.timestamp
    date -r `stat -f '%m' -t '%s' $1.log` '+D:%Y%m%d%H%M%S+000000' > $1.timestamp
```

- Give the file the executable bit

```
    chmod u+x creationdate.sh
```

- Put the following in the file before loading `datetime`

  ```
  \usepackage{catchfile}
  \ifdefined\pdfcreationdate\else
    \ifnum\shellescape=1
      \immediate\write18{./creationdate.sh \jobname}
      \CatchFileDef\pdfcreationdate{\jobname.timestamp}{\catcode`\D=12 }
    \fi
  \fi
  ```

Then your commands will give the required result. Of course one must check that `stat` and `date` accept the required command line options.

XeLaTeX *must* be run with the `-shell-escape` command line option, of course. If it isn't, then the behavior will be as without `\pdfcreationdate` available, that is, the seconds will always be "00". If the file is processed with pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, this definition of `\pdfcreationdate` will be ignored and `datetime` will be happy nonetheless, as those engines already have `\pdfcreationdate`.

On Windows a suitable batch script can be devised.

---

### Update July 2016

With the new `texosquery` script, the code can be simplified:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}

\ifdefined\pdfcreationdate\else
  \usepackage{texosquery}
  \TeXOSQueryNow{\pdfcreationdate}
  \edef\pdfcreationdate{\detokenize\expandafter{\pdfcreationdate}}
\fi

\usepackage{datetime}
\newtimeformat{hhmmss}{\twodigit{\THEHOUR}\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}\twodigit{\THESECOND}}
\settimeformat{hhmmss}
\begin{document}
\currenttime
\end{document}
```

I added `luatex85` in case LuaLaTeX is used. In this way, `-shell-escape` is only needed for XeLaTeX. The `\edef` with `\detokenize` is necessary, because `\TeXOSQueryNow` returns the starting `D` with category code “letter” and the macros in `datetime` assume category code “other” instead.

Note: the Java application, at the moment, seems only to run with Java 1.7.0_52 or later, but I was successful in recompiling it on 1.7.0_45. It would be nice if the application was made usable also with previous versions of Java.

Comment: Er, egreg, sorry to point this out, but `datetime` under LuaLaTeX works as is... But I've accepted your answer, as it does show the way for XeTeX.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough But this code is meant for XeLaTeX! I use `luatex` (better, `texlua`) only as an external command.

Comment: Ah! Doh, sorry..

Comment: @egreg: Yay! First LaTeX3, now Lua. I wish I could upvote it 10 times. `:)`

Comment: I don't know why your methods don't work when compiling XeLatex under MacTex.

Comment: @Kuttens What happens is that, on MacTeX, doing `\input|...` twice does nothing the second time. An issue I mentioned on the mailing list a few months ago, with no feedback.

Comment: @Kuttens Good news! See https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/147/ I'm confident the fix is good, but we have to wait for TL 2018.

Comment: @Kuttens It works for me.

Comment: @egreg It works now! I forget "-shell-escape"!

Answer (score 8):

you can use `lualatex` or `luatex` instead, no problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
Time: \luaexec{tex.print(os.date("\%X"))}

\end{document}
```

`luatex`:

```
Time: \directlua{tex.print(os.date("\%X"))}
\bye
```

[image]

or without the colons: `"\%H\%M\%S"`. All optional arguments:

```
%a  abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Wed)
%A  full weekday name (e.g., Wednesday)
%b  abbreviated month name (e.g., Sep)
%B  full month name (e.g., September)
%c  date and time (e.g., 09/16/98 23:48:10)
%d  day of the month (16) [01-31]
%H  hour, using a 24-hour clock (23) [00-23]
%I  hour, using a 12-hour clock (11) [01-12]
%M  minute (48) [00-59]
%m  month (09) [01-12]
%p  either "am" or "pm" (pm)
%S  second (10) [00-61]
%w  weekday (3) [0-6 = Sunday-Saturday]
%x  date (e.g., 09/16/98)
%X  time (e.g., 23:48:10)
%Y  full year (1998)
%y  two-digit year (98) [00-99]
%%  the character `%´
```

Comment: If you're using LuaTeX, you've already got `\pdfcreationdate` (or `\pdffeedback creationdate`

Comment: sure, but it is easier to modify the output with `os.date`