# Using shell escape to access system time

Tags: shell-escape, profiling

In [an earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32507/2707), I asked for analogs of `\pdfelapsedtime` (which measures the time since the start of the current run) in XeTeX and LuaTeX.  A LuaTeX solution was provided, and is now part of Heiko's `pdftexcmds` package.  However, no XeTeX solution was provided.  The only approach I can see to measuring time in XeTeX is to use shell-escape.

With pdfTeX on a Unix system I would build a wrapper around

```
\everyeof{\noexpand}
\catcode`\%=12
\message{\input|"date +%s.%N"}
```

(compile with `pdftex --shell-escape`).

1. Is there an analog of the `\input|...` construction for XeTeX? (When writing this question I thought that this construction would work.)
2. How can the system time be accessed in various os?

Comment: Does the `|` syntax work even on Windows when using MiKTeX? I have a feeling its TeX Live-specific.

Comment: @Joseph: Theoretically you can use the `|` syntax on miktex if you use the option `--enable-pipes`. `--shell-escape` is not needed. But the behaviour is inconsistent throught the engines: `\input "|date /t"` works fine with pdflatex, gives with lualatex an error, and no error but also no output with xelatex.

Comment: Could [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41893/4427) help?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for that: I knew I'd seen something on this topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Pipe support**

*pdfTeX* support pipes since version 1.40.0 (released 2007-01-01). From `NEWS`:

> shell escape: if the first character of a filename for `\openin`, `\openout`
>   `\input` is a pipe symbol (`|`), the filename is assumed to be a request for a
>   pipe to a command line that is given in the rest of the filename

The feature is enabled in different ways depending on the TeX distribution:

- TeX Live: --shell-restricted (default) allows some few commands to be called (e.g. kpsewhich, makeindex. See variable `shell_escape_commands` in `texmf.cnf`. Otherwise
  full shell escape rights are needed. They can be set by option `--shell-escape'.
- MiKTeX: Pipe support is activated by `--enable-pipes'. Shell escape options do not
  affect pipes.

Package `catchfile` (for plain and LaTeX formats) will add `\CatchPipeDef` and `\CatchPipeEdef` in version 2012/07/30 v1.6 to support pdfTeX's pipe feature.

*LuaTeX* does not have the same pipe feature of pdfTeX, because it has the Lua function `io.popen` that can be used for that purpose.
 Pacakge `pdftexcmds` provides `\pdf@pipe` as wrapper for convenience.

*XeTeX*: I could not get pipes running and working neither in TL2011/Linux nor MiKTeX 2.9.
 In the latter case I could only catch an empty line instead of the intended program output.

**OS independent command line**

Nowadays TeX distributions often include LuaTeX with its program `texlua`.
For example, the following Lua script prints the time in seconds since 1970-01-01:

```
if os.gettimeofday then
  print(os.gettimeofday())
else
  print(os.date("%s"))
end
```

Then the command call

```
texlua gettimeofday.lua
```

prints `1343650327.0485`, for example.

However if gettimeofday.lua is not in the current directory, `texlua` will not find
it, because its `kpathsea` module is not active. At least TL and MiKTeX provide
`kpsewhich` for finding the file.

Example for pdfTeX and the new version (2012/07/30 v1.6) of package `catchfile`:

```
\CatchPipeEdef\ScriptGettimeofday{kpsewhich gettimeofday.lua}{\endlinechar=-1}
\CatchPipeEef\CurrentTime{texlua \ScriptGettimeofday}{\endlinechar=-1}
```

Macro `\CurrentTime` contains the result. Or with low level commands (with e-TeX),
it is something like:

```
\begingroup
  \everyeof{\noexpand}%
  \endlinechar=-1 %
  \edef\file{\input |"kpsewhich gettimeofday.lua"}
  \xdef\CurrentTime{\input |"texlua \file"}
  % Use \@@input in LaTeX instead of the redefined \input
\endgroup
```

PS: The new version of package `catchfile`: [catchfile-1.6.pdf](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/catchfile-1.6.pdf)
(The `.dtx` file is attached to the PDF. Run `tex` on `catchfile.dtx` to
unpack the package.)

Answer to Bruno's comment:

If pipes are not available, then the ordinary write18 feature can be used.
However there are many downsides:

- Slower (file writing, searching and reading)
- The wrong file might be found. That can be tested by writing some
  random bytes in a file with the `write18` process and reading them
  back and checking, whether bytes are the same.
- The solution cannot be made expandable.
- More things that can break: File is not written (e.g. readonly directory),
  cannot be found, the wrong file is found, …
- Unique temporary file names needed to avoid conflicts in multi-user systems or multiple
  processes at the same time.
- Cleanup: Delete commands are again OS dependent (`rm` in Unix, `del` in Windows).
  or the temporary files remain.

Comment: Even without a pipe, it should be possible to use write18 to call texlua, write the result to a file, and input that file, no?  The pipe only makes the process easier, and allows for expandability.  Shell-escape should still let us define a `\settoelapsedtime<count register>` in XeTeX.

Comment: Actually I'm wondering about some of the limitations you describe.  Assume that I write a `\jobname.lua` file, then do `texlua \jobname.lua`, creating `\jobname.timestamp` (cf. my other answer).  Am I too naive to think that: (1) The correct file has to be found, since it is in the same directory.  (2) The directory cannot be readonly, otherwise the log, aux, pdf files could not be written there.  (3) Multi-user systems compiling the same `\jobname` in the same directory will break anyways with the log, pdf, etc. (4) Deleting can be done from within the lua script: `os.remove("\jobname.lua")`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch It is possible that the current directory is read-only. Therefore option `--output-directory` exists that redirects writes (`\openout`, `\write`) to the specified writable directory. However, at TeX macro level or inside shell escape commands this is unknown.

Comment: Thanks, @HeikoOberdiek.  In the case you describe, LaTeX's aux file mechanism will fail, for instance, and many other packages which require extra files too.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek it seems you did not release to CTAN that version, is there any reason (security perhaps) ?

Comment: @jfbu In short: lack of time.

Comment: would you know how to handle http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294185/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-input ? Using `\CatchPipeDef` seems to have the same problems.

Answer (score 5):

One approach, based on Heiko Oberdiek's answer to this question, and [egreg's answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41893/2707) is the code below.  It's made more complicated because I don't know how to pass parameters to a lua script interpreted using `texlua`, so I hard-code the parameter `\blf@time@base` in the lua file each time a function is called.

Since the absence of pipes in XeTeX forbids any expandable solution, the function `\pdf@setelapsedtime` should be called before each time `\pdf@elapsedtime` is used.  This solution using `\write18` has all the drawbacks noted in Heiko's answer.  In particular, each `\test` takes 0.1 seconds on my system, which is rather slow.

```
\catcode`\@=11
\newwrite\blf@time@write
\newread \blf@time@read
\gdef\blf@time@base{0}%
\protected\gdef\blf@time@aux#1#2%
  {%
    \begingroup
      \escapechar=-1
      \immediate\openout\blf@time@write\jobname.lua%
      \immediate\write\blf@time@write
        {%
          os.remove("\jobname.timestamp")
          if os.gettimeofday then
            time = os.gettimeofday()
          else
            time = os.date("\string\%s")
          end
          val = .5 + 65536 * (time - \blf@time@base)
          if val > 2147483647 then
            val = 2147483647
          end
          io.output("\jobname.timestamp"):write(string.format("%
            \string\%f\string\\n\string\%d", time, val))
        }%
      \immediate\closeout\blf@time@write
      \immediate\write18{texlua \jobname.lua}%
      \endlinechar-1%
      \immediate\openin\blf@time@read\jobname.timestamp
      \readline\blf@time@read to \blf@time@tmp
      #1%
      \readline\blf@time@read to \blf@time@tmp
      #2%
      \immediate\closein\blf@time@read
    \endgroup
  }%
\protected\gdef\pdf@resettimer
  {\blf@time@aux{\xdef\blf@time@base{\blf@time@tmp}}{}}%
\protected\gdef\pdf@setelapsedtime
  {%
    \blf@time@aux{}%
      {\protected\xdef\pdf@elapsedtime{\numexpr\blf@time@tmp\relax}}%
  }%
\pdf@resettimer
\pdf@setelapsedtime


\def\test
  {%
    \pdf@setelapsedtime
    \message{\the\pdf@elapsedtime}%
  }
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test\test
\bye
```

Compile with `xetex --shell-escape <filename>.tex`.