# Using Kile and PdfLaTeX with eps files

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps, kile

I'm aware there's a lot of questions regarding using eps files as graphics in pdfLaTeX, and have tried many 'fixes'/'get arounds' based on answers I've read on this forum (amongst others), but still can't get it to work.

I'm using Kile 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, having recently come from using TeXShop on a Mac.

I've read that in order to get Kile to compile my .tex file using PdfLaTeX I need to insert:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

in the preamble, which I have, but it still doesn't work. For example in a test .tex file I have included `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in the preamble, and then in the body written:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{pic1.eps}
\caption{\textit{A graphic.}}
\label{Label1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Upon running PDFLaTeX in Kile I get:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `pic1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

Which would suggest to me that epstopdf is doing SOMETHING, maybe putting the converted eps file somewhere silly?

Thanks in advance,
Olie

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}

Comment: Did you used the option --shell-escape, when you call PDFLATEX, graphics to automatically convert your eps into a pdf?

Comment: You can use a converter like http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/epstopdf.1.html to convert all your eps files into pdfs and use them.

Comment: Hi, I've tried putting the option --shell-escape in by going to settings>configure kile>build>PDFLaTeX, and adding that line of code in the options field, but it still spits out the same error when I hit PDFLaTeX - any ideas? I'd really prefer not to have to convert all graphics beforehand using a separate converter if at all possible.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Open the Terminal, and type `epstopdf` to see if this program has been installed. I think you did not install it correctly.

Comment: BTW, since TeX Live 2011 (Mac TeX 2011), the package `epstopdf` will be loaded automatically by the package `graphicx` if using `pdfLaTeX`.

Answer (score 3):

without the option `--shell-escape` it can't run external programs. Add it to Kile at `Settings->Configure Kile-> Build:

[image]

then the following should work:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{/tmp/titel2.eps}

\end{document}
```

`epstopdf` is loaded by default:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
/tmp/titel2-eps-converted-to.pdf
 ***********
```

You can test, if `epstopdf.sty` is installed. Run in a terminal:

```
kpsewhich epstopdf.sty
```

and it should report the location of the file:

```
voss@shania:~> kpsewhich epstopdf.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
```

If it outputs nothing then you have to install that package.

Comment: You don't need to add --write-enabled with recent versions of TeX Live as a restricted write is enabled by default now. Since the OP may be using Ubuntu's distribution of TeX, however, it might be necessary in that case.

Comment: sure, but it doesn't hurt if someone has an own `texmf.cnf` without an enabled `epstopdf`

Comment: Well it hurts in the sense that it opens the system to security vulnerabilities quite unnecessarily. By default --shell-restricted is enabled. Since this is sufficient for epstopdf, it would be better to recommend this in case the OP is on a system where it is not default rather than recommending they enable unrestricted write globally - especially if you are setting it in the preferences of the editor, which are liable to remain in place.

Comment: it can only open it to what is defined in `texmf.cnf`!

Comment: That's true of --shell-restricted. It is not true of --shell-escape that I know of. Are you sure --shell-escape is now equivalent to --shell-restricted? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65176/using-shell-escape-to-access-system-time. Is the information in the accepted answer there now obsolete?

Comment: you are absolutely right. I forgot that the programs listed in `texmf.cnf` are enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this as you don't give a MWE and I don't have an .eps to hand. However, I suspect that you need to include

```
\epstopdfsetup{suffix=.generated,prefersuffix=true}
```

in your preamble to tell the graphics package how to convert your eps images.

So you'd use something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{suffix=.generated,prefersuffix=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{pic1.eps}
\caption{\textit{A graphic.}}
\label{Label1}

\end{center}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Not having an eps to hand, though, I can't test this easily.

EDIT: Actually, I suspect from the error that you have such a rule but didn't include it in your question. In that case, do you have the programme epstopdf which you need to do the conversion? Perhaps this is not installed or is not being found for some reason. It should be part of your core TeX installation, though...